# How to run a pseudo-build on my vanilla JS project?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lint

i'm working with VSCode, and if you create a jsconfig.json you can set checkJS, the result is you will start getting syntax errors and type checking.
a long time ago i built a schema based on JSDoc that enables pretty solid type checking and casts.

now my problem is: the code is running even with errors, there is no build process. i want to have some kind of linting, that gives me all those type errors, but ideally without applying some other conventions on top of that, especially when i can't configure them
(e.g. i tried jslint, but first i don't find how to run it in the console on the whole solution and i can't suppress certain warnings)

i need a plugin, a linter, some solution that immediatly searches through the whole solution and gives proper errors.

please help me, and thanks for your time!

PS: please don't argue about whether JSDoc makes sense or whether i should use typescript, vanillaJS + JSDoc it is, i can't change that.

PS: i would like to edit that the linters ESLint, JSLint and JSLint are not the solution. i just renamed properties inside my type, got actual errors when opening files but the linter (using the recommended set) doesn't even care. so ... yeah. :(

Comment: I probably shouldn't be suggesting this as you're asking a question that is off-topic for SO, but have you taken a look at something a bit more modern than JSLint, like JSHint or ESLint which are much more configurable.

Comment: i will have a look on ESLint then, i think i tried JSHint out already, but it was also not quite what i expected, but ESLint sounds interesting, thanks :)
if it's out of scope for SO, then do you happen to know a platform where it's not out of scope? i even tried submitting a bug for VSCode once because they actually have an error console but it only works for the currently open document and a.t.m. i'm literally opening 10.000 files just to get those errors XD ridiculous

Comment: Check out the documentation for ESLint, you can run it from the command line against any number of files. I believe JSHint can also be run in a similar manner from the command line.

Comment: the problem with JSLint was primarily that i couldn't configure the warnings. i got some weird warning that i need to freeze exported classes.. and i got like hundreds. ideally i would like to only lint actually referenced files, but i guess that's too much to ask. as long as there's a wildcard pattern like **/*.js it's ok

Comment: _"ideally i would like to only lint actually referenced files"_ There's an argument for deleting JavaScript files that aren't actually being used. If you use source control (if not, why not) there's no danger of losing anything,

Comment: yes and no^^ it is generally valid, but there are also files that are referenced by another type of project. our storybook has completely different entry point but references some (!) files of our solution, i want those to be skipped because they have different linting prefrences. imports will not be found for those, long sad story. but it's okay, it's optional .)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246588/discussion-between-kyoshiro-kokujou-obscuritas-and-phuzi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after quite some time of research and tons of thinking in circles i go the solution.

you can basically run manually typescript type checking across your javascript solution. to do that you need to install typescript via

`npm install typescript --save-dev`
then in your tasks.json **OR** in your workspace file you have a tasks section. there you can create a tsc task that watches your whole environment for pending changes and write problems in the problems tab using the problemMathcer property, this will look somewhat like:

```json
{
            "label": "tsc",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
            "args": ["-p", "./jsconfig.json"],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never",
                "echo": false,
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "dedicated"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"},

 }
```

now, this task you would need to run using the terminal menu-item in the menu-bar of VSCode.
This is what the run-options object prevents (look above). This code is technically saying, run this task whenever you open the workspace.

now as of july 2022 there is something you need to do in addition to this. you need to press `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and look for `automatic tasks` and enable `Manage automatic tasks in folder` -> `Allow automatic tasks in folder`

but, as soon as VSCode Version 1.70.0 will be released, you can simply put this into your workspace:

`"task.allowAutomaticTasks": "on"`

in the settings section of your VSCode workspace.
this is important because the job is **ongoing**, so it doesn't complete and as such, VSCode does not send you any dialog or notification to enable them. so nothing will happen at all. (that alone caused two hours of research especially since the flag was a preview version feature)

maybe it helps someone else than me now.